# Expression error when using LookupSet?

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS 2012 report with an expression I am struggling with.

My report runs by a stored procedure. Each row in the stored procedure returns a Funding record. Each Funding record is attached to a Task record. Every Task can have one or more Funding records. Each Funding record may or may not have a Funding Company associated with it.
This means my data looks like this.

```
TaskID | FundingID | RCPFundingCompany
100      1000        Intel 
100      1001        IBM 
100      1002        TI 
101      1003        Intel 
101      1004        <null>
101      1005        <null>
102      1006        <null>
```

The RDL displays detail rows grouped by TaskID, effectively displaying one row per TaskID. All of that works fine. What I'd like to accomplish is to have the FundingCompany show up as a comma-separated list in one cell of the report, like this:

```
        Task ID     RCPFundingCompany
Row1    Task 100    Intel, IBM, TI
Row2    Task 101    Intel
Row3    Task 102
```

My first thought was to use the LookupSet function to concatenate these values into a single cell per row. 
So, I'm using this expression:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!RCPCompanies.Value, "TaskReviewSummary")
```

When I preview my report, I get this error:

```
Warning 1   [rsInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression used in textrun ‘Textbox10.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ returned a data type that is not valid.
```

What am I doing wrong? 
A-ha, I forgot the Join!

```
=(Join(LookupSet(Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!RCPCompanies.Value, "TaskReviewSummary"), ", "))
```

Unfortuntely, this results in the following results:

```
        Task ID     RCPFundingCompany
Row1    Task 100    Intel, IBM, TI
Row2    Task 101    Intel, 
Row3    Task 102    , , ,
```

Because the LookupSet is creating an array (if I understand correctly), it gathers the NULLs and then the join concatenates them all. Boo.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Join was causing problems with the NULLs in the LookupSet, I decided to eliminate the Join by putting my commas into the Stored Procedure.

So my data now looks like this:

```
TaskID | FundingID | RCPFundingCompany
100      1000        Intel, 
100      1001        IBM, 
100      1002        TI, 
101      1003        Intel, 
101      1004        <null>
101      1005        <null>
102      1006        <null>
```

Then I re-wrote my expression like this:

```
=IIF(Len(Join(LookupSet(Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!TaskID.Value, 
Fields!RCPCompanies.Value, "TaskReviewSummary"), ""))= 0, 
"",
Left((Join(LookupSet(Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!TaskID.Value, 
Fields!RCPCompanies.Value, "TaskReviewSummary"), "")),
abs(Len(Join(LookupSet(Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!TaskID.Value, 
Fields!RCPCompanies.Value, "TaskReviewSummary"), ""))-2)))
```

This expression first tests to see if the Concatenated set of data is longer than 0. If not, it prints nothing. If so, it joins the string together, and deletes the last comma. My data now looks perfect!!

So, did I do it wrong? Was there a better, more obvious, less complicated solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately the answer I originally submitted does not work because it does not eliminate duplicates. So some of my rows would look like this:
IBM, IBM, TI, TI, Intel

The quickest solution at this point was to use the For XML Path feature in the Stored procedure to concatenate the values, and to eliminate the use of the expression in SSRS to concatenate the values.